# unknown trap from Dell DRACs

Tags: linux, dell, snmp

I'm in the middle of an snmptrapd/snmptt deployment and I'm updating (via racadm) the configuration of all of my DRACs.  All but 3 of them sent me an expected "IPMI Alert Test Configuration" trap (.1.3.6.1.4.1.3183.1.1.0.0).

3 of my (newer, R710, DRAC6) hosts are sending me traps with an OID of .1.3.6.1.4.1.3183.1.1.0.1001.  I can't seem to find this documented anywhere and it has me a bit concerned.  Has anyone had any experience with this sort of deployment?

EDIT:  This looks like a bug.  The newer DELL-RAC-MIB defines an OID ending in .1001 as a IPMITestTrap, however the 1001 was appended to the old OID tree and sent on a subset of my servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first one just is just a test trap from when you configured a TRAP host in the snmp settings I suspect, does it persist? The other one I'm not sure about. Might be some sort of a "Link Up" for the DRAC, so you could throw and alert if you haven't received on in N seconds in your monitoring application.